# How to grab row and previous row from .csv file using Python?

Tags: python, pandas

I'm reading in a .csv file that looks something like this:

```
   DateTime             Failures
0  2020-05-27 00:10:49  0
1  2020-05-27 00:10:49  0
2  2020-05-27 00:21:55  0
3  2020-05-27 00:22:56  1
4  2020-05-27 00:22:59  0
```

What I'm trying to do is grab any row that has a failure along with the previous row.

I can get the rows with failures by using

```
log_file = pd.read_csv(self.input.text())

failures = log_file[log_file['Failures'] != 0]
```

but am unsure how to also grab the row before each failure.

I'm very new to Python and feel like there's probably an easy solution for my problem, I'm just not sure how to get it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `.shift` to also check a condition on the previous row. As the last row becomes `NaN` we'll fill with 0 so it doesn't accidentally get flagged by that part of the condition. (`.ne(0)` is the same as `!= 0`, just a preference)

```
df[df['Failures'].ne(0) | df['Failures'].shift(-1).fillna(0).ne(0)]

             DateTime  Failures
2 2020-05-27 00:21:55         0
3 2020-05-27 00:22:56         1
```

---

`.shift(-1)` brings all the values to the previous row

```
df['Failures'].shift(-1)

0    0.0
1    0.0
2    1.0     # Used to be 1 on row labeled with `3`
3    0.0
4    NaN     # Need to fill with 0 as NaN != 0 evaluates to True
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `.index` to capture the failure indexes and go from there.

```
indexes = log_file.index[log_file['Failures'] != 0].tolist()
```